# How does this Dax expression with SWITCH work?

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

```
mYear = SWITCH(MONTH(TODAY()),1,YEAR(TODAY())-1,YEAR(TODAY()))

mMonth = SWITCH(MONTH(TODAY()),1,12,MONTH(TODAY())-1)

mMonth_name = FORMAT(DATE(1,[mMonth],1),"MMM")
```

This measure is used in another expression or formula to get result for only previous month. What can I change in each measure to make me get values for YTD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn all about SWITCH() in the official docs:
(2 min to read)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax